Has Derrida elaborated on the importance of word order?
Derrida's différance suggest that Words and signs only acquire meaning through their differences from other words and signs. But in addition to difference from other words, word order is also important, for example, the cat is chasing the dog versus the dog is chasing the cat. The two sentences have the same words but the order is different and so have very different meaning. Have Derrida explained the importance of word order to meaning production? Thanks a lot.

That words acquire meaning through their "differences" (more precisely, through relations to each other and the overall "structure") is not Derrida's idea. It is a platitude of Saussure's structuralism inherited by all post-structuralists. And yes, the "structure" includes the order of words in particular per structural linguistics. Derrida's différance is a much more complex and loaded conception, fusing difference with deference, not focused on elementary grammar

See https://www.theawfulauthor.com/blog-1/2021/7/3/vive-la-diffrence

I have the idea that word order doesn't make a difference in some languages (Chinese?) but perhaps I am incorrect.

Thanks very much everyone. Yes I would say that word order or order of succession is in syntagmatic relations as Saussure explains. Also, in the Chinese language, word order is important to meaning.

@ScottRowe I think Latin with its 7 cases makes word order a minor feature, though be warned that linguists generally assert ANY difference in syntax hints at a difference in meaning. Even they changed word order for subtle distinctions in meaning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_grammar
